# Subsitute in this kale and grape recipe

Tags: substitutions

In [this recipe](http://www.thesilverpen.com/2013/03/15/hot-grapes-and-kale/), they list grapeseed oil. I don't have grapeseed oil and if I were to purchase it, I don't think I would use it that often. I have safflower oil, vegetable oil, canola oil, and extra virgin olive oil.

Do any of those make for a good substitute?

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/19366, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/31982, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/670, and probably others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost any fat, oil, butter, or lard will be fine for sauteing, although each may bring its own specific flavor.

If you are looking to most closely resemble grapeseed oil, choose a neutral flavored vegetable oil.  Any of the ones on your list other than olive oil will do just fine.

Comment: By no means am I saying you're answer is incorrect, but how come in Sweet72's post, only avocado oil is listed as a substitute? Is there some difference in smoke point or does that not really matter?

Comment: There is a difference in smoke point, but it doesn't matter in this application.  Avocado oil is also one of the neutral flavored vegetable oils I mentioned; I didn't call it out because it wasn't in your list of what you had available.  Avocado oil, like grapeseed, also tends to be expensive.

Comment: As to why he listed only that oil, I cannot speculate, other than to note it is the only one listed on the substitution reference site he linked, whereas I am going from first principals.

Answer (score 2):

Avocado Oil can be used as substitute for grapeseed oil..

To know more about substitutes for different oil, please see these links:

http://www.foodsubs.com/Oils.html